# MySQL combining outer joins

Tags: mysql, join

For this question I have created a simple example that illustrates what I am asking.

Say I had a table called 'books'

```
+----+----------------------------+-----------+
| pk |           title            | author_id |
+----+----------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | The Lost Symbol            |         1 |
|  2 | Follow Us Home             |         2 |
|  3 | The Man in the High Castle |         3 |
+----+----------------------------+-----------+
                (table a)
```

And another table called 'shops',  that had a list of shops that sold each book:

```
+----+---------+-------------+-------+
| pk | book_id |  shop_name  | price |
+----+---------+-------------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | WHSmith     |  5.00 |
|  2 |       1 | Waterstones |  7.00 |
|  3 |       1 | Amazon      |  2.50 |
|  4 |       2 | WHSmith     |  4.00 |
|  5 |       2 | Borders     |  4.50 |
+----+---------+-------------+-------+
                (table b)
```

If I do a simple `select` that grabs a book and all of the places it is sold using a `join` such as:

```
SELECT 
    books.*,
    shops.shop_name,
    shops.price
FROM 
    books
    JOIN shops ON books.pk = shops.book_id
WHERE 
    book.book_name = "The Lost Symbol"
```

I would get results such as below:

```
+----+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+
| pk |      title      | author_id |  shop_name  | price |
+----+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+
|  1 | The Lost Symbol |         1 | WHSmith     |  5.00 |
|  1 | The Lost Symbol |         1 | Waterstones |  7.00 |
|  1 | The Lost Symbol |         1 | Amazon      |  2.50 |
+----+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+
                      (table c)
```

However, I would LIKE to receive results like this:

```
+----+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+
| pk |      title      | author_id |  shop_name  | price |
+----+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+
|  1 | The Lost Symbol |         1 | NULL        |  NULL |
|  1 | The Lost Symbol |         1 | WHSmith     |  5.00 |
|  1 | The Lost Symbol |         1 | Waterstones |  7.00 |
|  1 | The Lost Symbol |         1 | Amazon      |  2.50 |
+----+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+
                        (table d)
```

I.e. the first row is just the result of left outer join and the rest of the results are the the inner join.

An even more desired outcome is:

```
+------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+
|  pk  |      title      | author_id |  shop_name  | price |
+------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+
|    1 | The Lost Symbol |         1 | NULL        |  NULL |
| NULL |            NULL |      NULL | WHSmith     |  5.00 |
| NULL |            NULL |      NULL | Waterstones |  7.00 |
| NULL |            NULL |      NULL | Amazon      |  2.50 |
+------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+
                          (table e)
```

Having `shop_name` and `price` concatenated and grouped in a single row seems not to work as it only does the first result from `shops` instead of all of them, also in my real world scenario, I have punctuation in the data so have to be careful with the separator.

So how would I get the result of table e?

Comment: Why do you want the format in table `e`, and what would that give you over table `c` ?

Comment: LEFT JOIN may be the solution, try to do LEFT JOIN. Cause LEFT JOIN gives the NULL property as well.

Comment: Look closely at his data.  `LEFT JOIN` won't give him what he is asking for.

Comment: You can do table d and e using unions, but I fail to see why you would need such an output.

Comment: You would not normally store books in the shops table. Instead, you would have a third table that relates shops to books (or shop PKs to book PKs)

Comment: table e is just better for my code over table c, and yes, I would have a third table normally, but I would still want the above outcome - this is a simplified example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to build the required result set:

```
SELECT pk, title, author_id, NULL AS shop_name, NULL AS price
FROM books
WHERE books.title = "The Lost Symbol"

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL AS pk, NULL AS title, NULL AS author_id, shops.shop_name, shops.price
FROM books
JOIN shops ON books.pk = shops.book_id
WHERE books.title = "The Lost Symbol"
```

The first part of the union operation returns the first row of the result, i.e. the book title. The second part returns the rest of the rows, i.e.the shop names.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10ae6/6)